# Input de imagen no me aparece en el formulario

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente código para que el usuario pueda subir una imagen a su perfil, el problema está en que el botón de seleccionar archivo no me aparece y no se el porqué.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form" action="actualizar_formulario.php" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" title="enter your first name if any.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">

                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Introduce tus dos apellidos" title="enter your last name if any.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">

                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico</h4></label>
                                              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@email.com" title="enter your email.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email"><h4>Provincia</h4></label><br>
                                              <select name="provincia">
                                                    <option value="">- selecciona -</option>
                                                    <option value="15">A coru&#241;a</option>
                                                    <option value="1">&#193;lava</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Albacete</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Alicante</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Almer&#237;a</option>
                                                    <option value="33">Asturias</option>
                                                    <option value="5">&#193;vila</option>
                                                    <option value="6">Badajoz</option>
                                                    <option value="7">Baleares</option>
                                                    <option value="8">Barcelona</option>
                                                    <option value="9">Burgos</option>
                                                    <option value="10">C&#225;ceres</option>
                                                    <option value="11">C&#225;diz</option>
                                                    <option value="39">Cantabria</option>
                                                    <option value="12">Castell&#243;n</option>
                                                    <option value="51">Ceuta</option>
                                                    <option value="13">Ciudad Real</option>
                                                    <option value="14">C&#243;rdoba</option>
                                                    <option value="16">Cuenca</option>
                                                    <option value="99">Extranjero</option>
                                                    <option value="17">Girona</option>
                                                    <option value="18">Granada</option>
                                                    <option value="19">Guadalajara</option>
                                                    <option value="20">Guip&#250;zcoa</option>
                                                    <option value="21">Huelva</option>
                                                    <option value="22">Huesca</option>
                                                    <option value="23">Ja&#233;n</option>
                                                    <option value="26">La rioja</option>
                                                    <option value="35">Las palmas</option>
                                                    <option value="24">Le&#243;n</option>
                                                    <option value="25">Lleida</option>
                                                    <option value="27">Lugo</option>
                                                    <option value="28">Madrid</option>
                                                    <option value="29">M&#225;laga</option>
                                                    <option value="52">Melilla</option>
                                                    <option value="30">Murcia</option>
                                                    <option value="31">Navarra</option>
                                                    <option value="32">Ourense</option>
                                                    <option value="34">Palencia</option>
                                                    <option value="36">Pontevedra</option>
                                                    <option value="37">Salamanca</option>
                                                    <option value="38">Santa cruz de tenerife</option>
                                                    <option value="40">Segovia</option>
                                                    <option value="41">Sevilla</option>
                                                    <option value="42">Soria</option>
                                                    <option value="43">Tarragona</option>
                                                    <option value="44">Teruel</option>
                                                    <option value="45">Toledo</option>
                                                    <option value="46">Valencia</option>
                                                    <option value="47">Valladolid</option>
                                                    <option value="48">Vizcaya</option>
                                                    <option value="49">Zamora</option>
                                                    <option value="50">Zaragoza</option>
                                                </select>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp" placeholder="Introduce tu código postal" title="enter a location">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="img_profile"><h4>Cambiar imágen de perfil</h4></label>
                                              <input type="file" class="text-center center-block file-upload">  
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <br>
                                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Guardar</button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Restablecer</button>
                                            </div>
                                      </div>
                                </form>
```

[image]

Comment: En el **HTML** que nos muestras no hay nada que pueda provocar que que el `<input>` no se vea. Quizá deberías **editar** la pregunta para añadir el **CSS** y el **HTML** necesarios para reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Voy a añadir html, el css no hay nada que afecte, estoy utilizando bootstrap 4

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para añadir tu código a un snnipet ejecutable, cargando las librerías de Bootstrap para que veas que en este caso el `<input>` puede verse correctamente. Luego debes de tener algo más que esté afectando a ese lemento y me decanto por **CSS**. Inspecciona el `<input>` con el inspector de elementos de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador y seguramente veas que le afectan reglas ajenas a Bootstrap.

Comment: Pues no lo entiendo, no veo el fallo por ningún lado

Comment: Inspecciona el `<input>` y actualiza tu pregunta con las reglas **CSS** que se le estén aplicando. Me temo que sin más datos poco podremos hacer desde aquí para ayudarte.